# displaying a decimal value as html boxes

Tags: html, css

[image: show values as colored representation]

I get a decimal number between 1 to 5 which I want to represent like the above mentioned image. This image for example shows a value `3.7`

What will be the best possible way to display it using `html + css`

Comment: this is possible without `javascript` easily if you can change your value to a percentage value

Comment: @Blowsie I was thinking that the OP needs to change values from 1 to 5 on some button click or something(which require javascript). I was expecting that from all. I misunderstood.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that you can turn the decimal into a percentage, this is doable with pure CSS. Or, you can use a small snippet of JavaScript to [set/adjust the percentage value](http://jsfiddle.net/GqK6p/4/).

[image]

*IE7+, Chrome, etc.*

### Example 1

Simple example, no script, minimal markup: http://jsfiddle.net/GqK6p/6/

**HTML**

```
<div id="progress"></div>
<ul id="mask">
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
</ul>
```

**CSS**

```
#wrapper { position: relative; height: 30px; width: 180px; }
#progress { position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0; z-index: 0; background-color: red; width: 74%; height: 100%; }
#mask { position: absolute; z-index: 1; height: 100%; }
LI { float: left; border: 4px solid #aaa; height: 22px; width: 22px; }
```

### Example 2

A bit more polished example, allowing for inner styling of each box: http://jsfiddle.net/GqK6p/2/

This also shows the usage of percentage-based width for the bar.

**HTML**

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="progress"></div>
    <ul id="mask">
        <li><div></div></li>
        <li><div></div></li>
        <li><div></div></li>
        <li><div></div></li>
        <li><div></div></li>
        <li><div></div></li>
    </ul>  
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#wrapper { position: relative; height: 30px; width: 180px; }

/* set width to whatever percentage makes sense based on decimal value */

#progress { position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0; z-index: 0; background-color: red; 
    width: 59%; height: 100%; }

#mask { position: absolute; z-index: 1; height: 100%; }
LI { float: left; border: 4px solid #aaa; height: 22px; width: 22px; }
LI > DIV { border: 1px solid #555; height: 20px; }
```

### Example 3

Here's an animated variation which shows how to dynamically adjust the width of the progress bar with JavaScript: http://jsfiddle.net/GqK6p/4/

```
var progress = $("#progress");
var width = 0; // use whatever starting value makes sense

setInterval(function(){

    // increment/process as desired
    if( ++width > 100 ){
         width = 0;
    }        

    progress.css("width",  width + "%");       
}, 25);​
```

### HTML 5 Progress Element

As a side note, the HTML 5 `progress` element would probably be the semantic choice for this type of information, but [browser support isn't complete yet](http://www.useragentman.com/blog/2012/01/03/cross-browser-html5-progress-bars-in-depth/), and I don't think any capability exists to style `progress`.

Answer (score 0):

You could do this with a UL and some DIVs.

```
<ul>
<li>
    <div class="on"></div>
    <div class="on"></div>
    <div class="on"></div>
    <div class="on"></div>
    <div class="on"></div>
    <div class="on"></div>
    <div class="on"></div>
    <div class="on"></div>
    <div class="on"></div>
    <div class="on"></div>
</li>
```

Here's a quick example:

http://jsfiddle.net/EfpPr/5/

Obviously you'd just need a little bit of javascript/jQuery to set the DIVs to be on/off as required.

Comment: Why would you even wrap that in an unordered list? The list does nothing.

Comment: @DanMan - The list LI elements serve as containers for the DIV elements which make up each block. Alternatively you could contain the DIVs in DIVs themselves instead of using the UL/LI combination or use any other tag you felt like. I simply felt that a UL was a nice simple solution.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your markup, which you haven't posted, I'd go for 2 background images. One with the red bar in it, and the other with all the boxes, which are transparent in the middle. Then, with a little calculation (mapping your 1-5 range to either percent or pixels), you just shift the red bar around with `background-position`.

You won't see a difference when the bar ends up behind one of the opaque areas, but that's not too bad, is it?